# Refreshing a page in React web application

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

Which method will get executed when I refresh a page in react web application.

I have a application when I go to the link `http://localhost:3000/#/` Login page will appear after logging in the URL will be `http://localhost:3000/#/devices`

And now if I refresh the page again the URL will be `http://localhost:3000/#/`
which should be `http://localhost:3000/#/devices` how to handle this refreshing ?

Which file will get executed when I refresh a page at `http://localhost:3000/#/devices`

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: You open a page on localhost. -> You login. -> You open an external page. -> You refresh the page. Is this the flow ? Do you have any routes configured for this url?

Comment: not an external page, same application running in the local server

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing a lot of headache that comes with routing by using something like [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

Then you can do something like:

```
<Route exact path="/#/devices" component={DevicesComponent}/>
```

This way you when you refresh the React App will know what component to load on that URL!

Hope this helps.